# How to write to logfile with quercus

Tags: php, quercus

I'm running quercus 4.0.25 on apache tomcat 1.7 and I've finally managed to get php running. However I cannot seem to get my php settings regarding writing to logfiles running.

I've tried these following settings in my web.xml file:

1.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>ini-file</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/php.ini</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and 2.

```
<init>
  <ini-file>WEB-INF/php.ini</ini-file>
</init>
```

With the following settings in my `php.ini`-file:

```
display_errors = Off 
error_reporting = E_ALL | ~E_STRICT 
html_errors =Off 
log_errors = On 
error_log = "C:/Logs/php/quercus_php.log"
```

But for some reasons `quercus` doesn't write to this file. Is there something that I'm missing or some configuration that is off the wall?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this for 4.0.36.  If you like, you check out our svn repository to try out the fix.

http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=4178